# Is it necessary to check refresh tokens ownership to issue new access tokens?

Tags: python, jwt, refresh-token

I'm not sure to really understand [how refresh tokens are supposed to be stored/checked](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/refreshing-access-tokens/). From this reference and other things I've read I feel like it makes sense to store ownership of every refresh token. This information can then be used to revoke some given user's refresh tokens and also to create new access token for the specified user. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

But does it make sense to try to check the user's identity when he tries to get new access token? For example, I just have this simple check in the *refresh token endpoint*:

```py
async def refresh_access_token(request):
    data = await request.form()
    query = database.session.query(RefreshToken)
    refresh_token = query.filter(RefreshToken.id == data['refresh_token']).first()
    if refresh_token is None or refresh_token.expires < utcnow():
        raise SomeError("...")
```

And this is pretty much the only thing I do before issuing a new access token for the user associated with this `refresh_token` (I send a second request to get the user from my database using the owner's identifier from this `refresh_token`).

Would it make sense to also ask the user for its identity? For example using a (potentially expired) access token? Or should the refresh token be self sufficient?

Again, for the example and maybe disambiguation:

```py
    access_token = request.headers['Authorization']
    payload = jwt.decode(access_token, str(JWT_SECRET_KEY), options={'verify_exp': False})
```

The code `jwt.decode` would raise [InvalidSignatureError](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jwt.exceptions.InvalidSignatureError) if the signature didn't match. (`jwt` come from [PyJWT](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).

Is adding this kind of identity check before issuing the new access token  bad/good/essential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it necessary to check refresh tokens ownership

The short answer here would be no it's not apart of any OAuth2 RFC.

However something that an application may enforce is the refresh token and client id and/or secret association.

A refresh request should look like the example below

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: authorization-server.com

grant_type=refresh_token
&refresh_token=xxxxxxxxxxx
&client_id=xxxxxxxxxx
&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxx
```

No other client should have the secret associated to a given refresh token, each client typically is only given one so many application check the "ownership" of the refresh token to make sure it has not been compromised.

Comment: Does having this extra layer add a bit of security even for publicly available applications? I have not much ideas on attacks so I can't really tell. Somewhat I think my question to your answer would be: is there any chance that someone manages to steal a refresh token without knowing the identity of the owner? (in the case of a client ID verification). In the case where the client is not public I imagine that using the client secret is something that would on the other hand add an extra level of security?

Comment: A thin layer at least against attacks, the response from auth server do not include the client's secret, if those were spied one attack could be prevented by checking/comparing ownership. Memory spying attacks usually produce partial results so it's reasonable that the refresh token was leaked by not the secret.